# css issue with menu in IE

Tags: css

The following page has a top menu with children.

http://www.businesseventsydney.com.au/about-us/

In IE9, if you mouse into the children a little slowly, the child menu suddenly disappears. It is as if it hits a single pixel of space or something, which causes the menu to collapse. You need to move quickly into the child menu to avoid this collapse happening.
Can anyone spot what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

change padding-bottom from 14px to 17px

```
#top-nav li a
{
    padding-bottom:17px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change #top-nav li ul whit this maybe helpful

```
#top-nav li ul { 
 position : absolute;
 margin : 33px 0 0px 0;
 padding : 0 ;
 width : 184px;
 clear : both;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 z-index : -1;
 left: -999em;
 text-align: left;
 border-bottom: none !important;
}
```